# Java glazedlists: how to update a table row

Tags: java, swing, glazedlists

I'm missing something obvious here.

I have a [glazedlists](http://sites.google.com/site/glazedlists/) `EventList<X>` where `X` is my custom class. This list contains a bunch of values. When I update one of the values, how do I make sure the GUI updates its display for that row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this appears to be to replace the list element with itself:

```
 EventList<X> list = /* get reference to a list */
 X x = list.get(3);
 /* update x here */
 list.set(3,x);
```

Comment: I am using basiceventlist and the elements are regular POJOs. And it works as if the beans are 'obserbable', no need to set() after modifying one element.How can that be?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you can invoke [addListEventListener](http://publicobject.com/glazedlists/glazedlists-1.8.0/api/) to register a [ListEventListener](http://publicobject.com/glazedlists/glazedlists-1.8.0/api/ca/odell/glazedlists/event/ListEventListener.html). See also the [Glazed Lists Tutorial](https://docs.google.com/Doc?id=dc5md22b_0g456kwd8).

Answer (score 1):

The [FAQ](http://www.glazedlists.com/documentation/faq) mentiones two ways under the question:

> How do I tell Glazed Lists that an Object in my EventList has been updated?

Either you use the get/set approach as pointed out by Jason, or you make the elements in the list observable by for instance the  `PropertyChangeListener` and then use the `ObservableElementList`. I think this second approach is cleaner and it should also work with concurrent threads.

Comment: I am using basiceventlist and the elements are regular POJOs. And it works as if the beans are 'obserbable', no need to set() after modifying one element. How can that be?